# How to force Query engine to return data from right partition without .$Partition function ?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, partitioning

We partitioned a table based on IsActive(bit) flag. Almost %70 out of 500k rows are current and we wanted to write old and new rows in 2 different partitions.  However when I want to return data from the table I see difference in execution time and I/O cost when I run these two queries.

SELECT [columns] FROM TableX 
WHERE $PARTITION.partition_function_name(IsActive) = 2 -- partition has active records.

SELECT [columns] FROM TableX 
WHERE IsActive = 1 -- Returns active rows

Is there a way to avoid using $PARTITION.partition_function_name(IsActive) = 2 
statement. I was assuming since table partitioned by IsActive column it should automatically read from right partition and return me with less cost.

Execution Plan Details

[With $PARTITION.partition_function_name(IsActive) = 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwaZy.png)

[with IsActive = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaYSQ.png)

Comment: For columns of the `bit` data type, you need either a variable or an explicit cast: `where IsActive = cast(1 as bit)`.

Comment: Thanks @RogerWolf it magically worked for me. But I am not quite sure why engine did not pick the value as bit. Column datatype is bit but I assume engine thinks it is a bool value ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you assume incorrectly. By default, integer literals are treated as `int`, decimals as `float`, and so on.